# how to prove this fraction is at its lowest terms?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was asked to prove that $\frac{a^3+2a}{2a^4+5a^2+1}$ is in its lowest terms.

I tried by classifying the situation according to whether $a$ is odd or even, and find that the nominator and the denominator cannot both be odd or even, does this complete the proof?

Comment: No. You have to prove that they never have a common factor. You've only proved that 2 is never a common factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$2a^4+5a^2+1-a(2a^3+5a)=1\implies(a,2a^4+5a^2+1)=?$$

$$2a^4+5a^2+1=2a^2(a^2+2)+(a^2+2)-1=(a^2+2)(2a^2+1)-1$$
$$\implies(a^2+2,2a^4+5a^2+1)=1$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399223/is-this-condition-necessary-for-two-numbers-to-be-coprime