# Is this condition necessary for two numbers to be coprime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Using Euclidean Algorithm, one could show that, suppose $hcf(x,y)=1$ then $ax+by=1 \ \text{for some} a,b \in \mathbb Z$

But is it true that if two numbers $x,y$ satisfy $ax+by=1 \ \text{for some} a,b \in \mathbb Z$, then it must be such that $hcf(x,y)=1$,namely $x$ and $y$ are coprime?

Comment: It is obvious: any common divisor would have to divide 1.

Comment: @EugenCovaci , I see, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p$ divides $x$ and $y$. Then $p$ divides $ax+by=1$. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are not coprime. That is, the have a common divisor, $d$, bigger than $1$. Define $m$ and $n$ such that $x=dm$ and $y=dn$; by the definition of $d$, these are both integers.

If we had $ax+by=1$, we would have $a(dm)+b(dn)=1$, or $d(am+an)=1$. This means that $d$ is a factor of $1$, which is impossible.

For example, we know that there's no solution to $6a+15b=1$, because this implies that $1$ is a multiple of $3$.